# Nasm how to access dds and dws under a specific label?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing

Considering the following label:

```
foo:
    dw 0
    dd 0
```

Now how can one access the double word or `dd`(word?) under the `foo` label from another label?

```
bar: ;Subroutine
    mov eax, [foo] ;Now how can I move the value stored in foo's dw into eax for example?
                   ;I assume this isn't the correct way?
    add eax, 01h   ;Do something with the value
    mov [foo], eax ;Store it back into foo's dw
    ret
```

I am aware that there may be answers to this in documentations etc. but I'm lacking the proper terminology to find any good results using Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dw` declares a *word*, which on x86 platforms is 16 bits. The size of `eax` is 32 bits (a doubleword). Hence, using `mov eax,[foo]` would usually be a bad idea.

Imagine that you have the following:

```
foo: dw 0x1122
     dd 0x33445566
```

What you'd get in `eax` if you did `mov eax,[foo]` is `0x55661122`. The CPU just reads whatever it finds at the given address as if it was a doubleword (so long as you don't try to access data not allocated to your program), without caring about what that data might be.

If you want to get just `0x1122` you could read it into `ax` (the low word of `eax`): `mov ax,[foo]`. Note that the upper word of `eax` will remain unchanged.

If you want to get `0x1122` into `eax` you should use the zero-extending variant of `mov`: `movzx eax,word [foo]`. This will read just the first word located at `foo`, zero-extend it into a doubleword, and place the result in `eax`.

If you wanted to read the doubleword you've declared (`0x33445566` in my example), you would use `mov eax,[foo+2]`.

Comment: Thank you for good answer. Btw what does the `d` stand for then if it's not for word?

Comment: Depends on which `d` you're talking about. If you mean the first `d` in `db`/`dw`/`dd`/etc, then it probably stands for something like _declare_. The second `d` in `dd` stands for `dword` or `doubleword` (which on the x86 is 32 bits).

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer: I think `db/dw/dd` stands for `data byte/word/dword`, or maybe `define byte/word/dword`.  I don't think "declare" makes sense, because declare is something you do with labels, not data. `foo:` delcares the label.  You can have either one without the other.

Answer (score 1):

data segment:

```
foo dw 0
    dd 0
    db 0,0
```

code segment:

```
bar:
xor eax, eax  ; set eax to zero
mov ax, [foo] ; get a word from DS:foo into ax (low word of EAX)

add eax, 01h
mov [foo], ax ; Store it back into foo's dw
ret
```

Some more access variations.

accessing a dword:

```
mov eax, [foo+2] ; get a dword word from DS:foo+2 into eax
mov [foo+2], eax ; Store it back
```

accessing a byte:

```
mov al, [foo+6] ; get a byte from DS:foo+6 into al (low byte of ax)
```